# Having problems loading a jpg file using libjpeg

Tags: libjpeg

I need to load jpg files in my application. I used libjpeg to save JPGs (from processed raw files) and it works nicely.

Reading them though is a different issue. I am getting very weird results, the image is very distorted, in 12 columns, which are mostly gray scale.

I followed the example, and the only modification I made is how to put the data in my buffer (the put_scanline_someplace() function is missing from the example.

Here is my relevant code (I need the data in BGR format):

```
dest=0;
while(cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height)
{
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
    src=0;

    for(i=0;i<cinfo.output_width;i++)
    {
        image_buffer[dest*3+2]=buffer[src*3+0];
        image_buffer[dest*3+1]=buffer[src*3+1];
        image_buffer[dest*3+0]=buffer[src*3+2];
        src++;
        dest++;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. buffer isa pointer to an array of ints, so the code that works is like so:

```
        image_buffer[dest*3+2]=buffer[0][src*3+0];
        image_buffer[dest*3+1]=buffer[0][src*3+1];
        image_buffer[dest*3+0]=buffer[0][src*3+2];
```